# compile visual studio solution command line

Tags: c, node.js, visual-studio-2015, compilation

I'm trying to build a VS solution command line, just with the cmd.

I can do it by launching the devenv console, then run devenv command etc... This work, but I have to do it with the cmd, because I use nodejs to run it, and I need to get the output.

Does anybody has a solution ?

Comment: post the code and the actual sequence of steps taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual with Visual C++, you open a command prompt window using one of "Tools" shortcuts ("VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt" or others located in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2015\Visual Studio Tools\Windows Desktop Command Prompts` ).

In this console window, `cd` to your code and compile. Execute CL or run your makefile or msbuild.

Unfortunately, in VS2015  these shortcuts are more fragile than in previous VS versions, so YMMV.